# HTTP interceptor like MITM on the server

Tags: httpinterceptor

For debugging purposes, I would like to have an interception program which logs traffic in and out of a Linux (Centos 7) server. MITM seems more like a client-side solution. I would like to know what FOSS solutions are available.